# Compiling java programs from CLI using javac

Tags: javac

I have the following directory structure form where I am invoking javac

> src/ lib/ build/

Under src:

> src/com/xyz/App.java -- contains the main class 
>   src/com/xyz/base/j1.java  
>   src/com/xyz/base/j2.java  
>   src/com/xyz/exceptions/e1.java  
>   src/com/xyz/hibernate/factory/hbf1.java  
>   src/com/xyz/hibernate/helper/hbh1.java

Under lib:

> lib/hibernate.jar
>
> lib/commons.jar

At the top level, I am using the following javac command:

> javac  -verbose -classpath lib/hibernate.jar:lib/commons.jar  -d ./build -sourcepath ./src com/xyz/*.java

and I receive the following output

> javac: No match

How should the args be passed to javac?

And here is the **ANSWER**:

> javac -verbose -d build -classpath lib/commons.jar:lib/hibernate.jar [complete path for ALL the directories]/*.java

Comment: csh considered harmful.

Comment: `javac -d build -classpath lib/commons.jar:lib/hibernate.jar src/*`

Answer (score 0):

javac won't expand wildcards, that's what your shell does. so when you specify com/xyz/*.java  , that will not expand to anything, as those files are under src/ but the shell doesn't know that. If you list out every java file as com/xyz/Foo.java com/xyz/Bar.java etc, it should work.

(note that if you're on windows you'll need ; and not : to seperate classpaths)

Something like this might work:

```
javac -verbose -classpath build:lib/hibernate.jar:lib/commons.jar -d ./build  ./src/com/xyz/base/*java ./src/com/xyz/exceptions/*.java ./src/com/xyz/hibernate/factory/*.java ./src/com/xyz/*.java
```

I'd not do this other than as an exercise on how to compile from a command line, otherwise use a build tool like [ant](http://ant.apache.org/)

Comment: before I compile from ant, I am curious to know the build process.. that's why all my effort

Comment: Fails with what ? How ? Where ? Possibly some source directories were missing, like ./src/com/xyz/*.java

Comment: Why do I need to include the dir "build" in the classpath? i.e. javac -classpath build:lib/hibernate.jar:lib/commons.jar

Comment: javac -verbose -classpath build:lib/commons.jar:lib/hibernate.jar -d build ./src/com/xyz/base ./src/com/xyz/App.java ./src/com/xyz/hibermate/factory/*.java ...

Comment: So compiled classes can be resolved when something that depends on them is compiled. Anyway, What, specfiically, is the *exact* error you are getting ? Please post the output instead of "it failes"

Comment: I am using hibernate annotations. Do I need to use an annotation processor for use with javac?

Comment: OK>. folks.. I got the build process to complete. Now how do I execute the program?

Comment: java ./build/com/xyz/App -- generates the error "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: "

Comment: @user350129 You need to tell it the class path and the class that contains the main method to start `java -classpath build:lib/commons.jar:lib/hibernate.jar com.xyz.App`